# Prove that the Fourier transform of an integrable function f satisfies $\lim_{|n| \rightarrow \infty} c_{n}(f) = 0$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Prove that the Fourier transform of an integrable function $f$ satisfies:

$$\lim_{|n| \rightarrow \infty} c_{n}(f) = 0$$

where the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of an integrable function $f$ is defined as the sequence $(c_{n}(f))_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$,
where $c_{n}(f)$ is the Fourier coefficient of a function $f \in L^{1}([-L,L])$, and is defined to be $$c_{n}(f) = \frac{1}{2L}\int^{L}_{-L} f(x) \overline{g_{n}(x)}dx = \langle f,g_{n}\rangle.$$
And for $L>0$ and for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we take $$g_{n}(x) = e^{in\pi x/L}. $$

Could anyone give me a hint, please?

Comment: This is the *Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the *Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma*. It's in lots of books. One way to prove it is to approximate $f$ by a step function, and for step functions it can be proved by direct calculation.

Comment: Which book do u recommend?

Comment: I found a proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784556/riemann-lebesgue-lemma   which is $90%$ close to what I want ...... the only problem that I have is that this solution for $L^{1}(-\infty,\infty)$ but I want it for $L^{1}(-L,L)$ so I have a problem with the boundary of the integration. could u suggest for me what shall I do?

Comment: @weakmathematician Just think of your function on $(-L,L)$ as a function on $\Bbb R$ by defining it as zero outside the interval.

Comment: but does not that violates the definition of the Fourier coefficients given above in my question and hence violates the definition of the Fourier transform?

Comment: or shall I do what is done here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256586/riemann-lebesgue-lemma-clarification

Comment: A common way is to approximate $f$ by continuosly differentiable functions with compact support.